# wordpress upload permission on nginx & ubuntu

Tags: uploads, permissions

I have a problem with wordpress upload folder permission on nginx/ubuntu VPS.

keep getting the error:

> “asr.jpg” has failed to upload due to an error Unable to create
>   directory uploads/2014/02. Is its parent directory writable by the
>   server?

here are my uploads folder settings:

`drwxrwxr-x  8 www-data www-data 4096 Feb  6 14:41 uploads`

I also check that wordpress/php is running as the www-data user.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The issue was tedious WordPress settings oversight. Completely forgot to check `uploads` folder location after server migration; check for upload folder setting under `Settings/Media`.

Comment: Please accept your own answer.

Comment: Please accept your own answer.